# Newtonsoft call custom Converter for property of type Object

Tags: c#, json.net

Is it possible to call a custom converter when the type of the Property is Object.

For example given a class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Object o { get; set; }
}
```

and another class:

```
public class Inner
{
    public string s { get; set; }
    public Inner(string s)
    {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

and a converter:

```
class MyConverter : JsonConverter<Inner>
{
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Inner? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override Inner? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Inner? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // I would like this to be called.
    }
}
```

How can newtonsoft be configured to call `ReadJson()` when running:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer()
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new MyConverter());
serializer.Configure(settings);
Foo f = new Foo()
{
    o = new Inner("hello")
};

var json = serializer.ToJson(f);
var resultingFoo = serializer.FromJson<Foo>(json)
```

It Looks like newtonsoft wont find `MyConverter` since the type of the property on `Foo` is `Object`.

I notice that the JSON it is deserializing contains the required `Type` information:

```json
{
  "$type": "Octopus.IntegrationTests.Tools.Foo, Octopus.IntegrationTests",
  "o": {
    "$type": "Octopus.IntegrationTests.Tools.Inner, Octopus.IntegrationTests",
    "s": "hello"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to make use of that `$type` field to select the converter to use?

The property may have other types set on it and those types should fall back to the default behaviour.

Comment: Once a converter is applied, it's the responsibility of the converter to do **everything** including processing of type information.  For examples of how to process the `"$type"` property within `JsonConverter.Read()` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36587265/3744182) to [How to deserialize json objects into specific subclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36584071/3744182) and also [Using custom JsonConverter and TypeNameHandling in Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29810004/3744182).

Comment: Do those two questions answer your question also?